# hiding and displaying uitoolbar on same button click

Tags: iphone

I have an button on UIToolbar. i need to display another toolbar on clicking that button and upon same button click , it must be hide. I am able to display toolbar but how to hide the toolbar on same button click?? help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `tag` property of your button.

```
if(myButton.tag = 0) // means Do hide 
{
    myToolBar.hidden = YES;
    myButton.tag = 1;
}
else 
{
  myToolBar.hidden = NO;
  myButton.tag = 0;
}
```

Comment: @user720235  : Yes it can be change (the tag value) more than one time ,it depend on your requirement,Most of the coder use the above mentioned approach in the similar situation which you have.

Comment: @jhaliya: in viewDidLoad method i used 'mytoolbar.hidden = YES' coz i dont want to show, when view is loaded. button on button click i want ot show and hide also on same click

Comment: @jhaliya: its not working when i write the code in (IBAction) method

Comment: @user720235 : Why ? could u explain ?

Comment: @jhaliya: when i used the break point ,then control check if block statement and directly run the else part. i already checked tag value in attribute window. its zero.

Comment: @user720235 : check once again carefully .

Comment: @jhaliya: i have displayed uitoolbar in IB so it must display as soon as view is loaded .. i guess the code is working in reverse direction. what u think!!

Answer (score 0):

How do you hide? If you use `hidden: YES` just change it to `hidden: NO`

Comment: Brattberg:  in viewDidload method i used 'hidden:NO' coz i dont want to display it first. Then on button click i set 'hidden:YES', but how to make it again hide on same button click??

Comment: Hide again? Just set `hiddden:YES`again?

Comment: sorry for my mistake. In viewDidload method i used 'hidden:YES' coz i dont want to display it first. Then on button click i set 'hidden:NO
', but how to make it again hide on same button click??

Comment: Try `[btn hidden:![btn isHidden]];`